# Nested JSON to Dataframe using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and trying to extract the data from JSON object to table format using Dataframe

Sample structure of JSON

```
{
    "subject": "Computer",
    "records": [
      {
        "name": "Section A",
        "elements": [
          {
            "type": "easy",
            "name": "Section A Module 1",
            "elements": [
              {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "SectionQ1",
                "title": "Some question?",
                "readOnly": true
              },
              {
                "type": "text",
                "name": "SectionQ2",
                "title": "some other question?",
                "isRequired": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "title": "Section A details"
      },
      {
        "name": "Section B",
        "elements": [
          {
            "type": "medium",
            "name": "Section B Module 1",
            "elements": [
              {
                "type": "radiogroup",
                "name": "SectionQ1",
                "title": "some question?",
                "choices": [
                  {
                    "value": "1",
                    "text": "Choose 1"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "2",
                    "text": "Choose 2"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "3",
                    "text": "Choose 3"
                  }
                ],
                "colCount": 3
              },
              {
                "type": "radiogroup",
                "name": "SectionQ2",
                "title": "some other question?",
                "description": "question 2",
                "isRequired": true,
                "choices": [
                  {
                    "value": "value 1",
                    "text": "choice 1"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "value 2",
                    "text": "choice 2"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "value 3",
                    "text": "choice 3"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "title": "title"
          }         
        ],
        "title": "Title"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm trying to get inner `elements` array as table linking to outer `elements`.
so table could be `inner_elements`, `outer_elements` , `records`.

I have tried to below code along with few other approaches.

```
df = pd.read_json (r'sample.json')
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
print(df)
```

The expected output will be like

```
dataframe records

Name        Title
Section A   Section A details
Section B   Section B details


dataframe elements1

Key(records)    Type    Name
Section A       easy    Section A Module 1
Section B       medium  Section B Module 1


dataframe elements2

Key(elements1)          type        name        title                   readOnly    Description     isRequired  colCount
Section A Module 1      text        SectionQ1   Some question?          true
Section A Module 1      text        SectionQ2   some other question?    true
Section B Module 1      radiogroup  SectionQ1   some question?                                                  3
Section B Module 1      radiogroup  SectionQ2   some other question?                question 2      true


dataframe choice

Key(elements2)          type        name        value       text    
Section B Module 1      radiogroup  SectionQ1   1           Choose 1
Section B Module 1      radiogroup  SectionQ1   2           Choose 2
Section B Module 1      radiogroup  SectionQ1   3           Choose 3
Section B Module 1      radiogroup  SectionQ2   value 1     choice 1
Section B Module 1      radiogroup  SectionQ2   value 2     choice 2
Section B Module 1      radiogroup  SectionQ2   value 3     choice 3
```

However not getting any clue to could I proceed further. Please guide me to achieve the same

Comment: How will the output dataframe look like ?

Comment: Thank you for comment,each array should be the separate dataframe but should have relation with other dataframe with some key.

Comment: Hi @Sushanth I have added the expected output in the question it self. Please take a look and let me know if you can help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract nested arrays from a JSON object, I'd like to do something similar to MongoDB's [`unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). In fact, I'd try to mimic Mongo's aggregation pipelines. The package [`toolz`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/) can really help with that.

First there's the *explode* operation, where a record containing an array field gets expanded into a sequence of records identical to the original but with the value for the key in question replaced by the corresponding array element.

Something like this:

```py
from toolz.dicttoolz import assoc_in, get_in

def explode(d, keys):
    values = get_in(keys, d)
    if isinstance(values, list):
        for v in values:
            yield assoc_in(d, keys, v)
    else:
        yield d


record = {"x": 1, "y": [1, 2, 3]}
assert list(explode(record, ["y"])) == [{"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": 1, "y": 3}]
```

To create the `unwind` stage, the `explode` operation needs to be applied a sequence of records:

```py
from toolz.itertoolz import concat

def unwind(iterator, keys):
    return concat(map(lambda d: explode(d, keys), iterator))

records = [{"x": 1, "y": [1, 2, 3]}, {"x": 2, "y": [4, 5]}]
assert list(unwind(records, ["y"])) == [
    {"x": 1, "y": 1}, 
    {"x": 1, "y": 2}, 
    {"x": 1, "y": 3},
    {"x": 2, "y": 4},
    {"x": 2, "y": 5},
]
```

Now you can create the pipelines to extract the tables you want:

```py
from toolz import curried
from toolz.functoolz import pipe

sections = pipe(data["records"],
                curried.map(lambda d: {
                    "section": get_in(["name"], d),
                    "title": get_in(["title"], d),
                }),
                list,
)

modules = pipe(data["records"],
               lambda i: unwind(i, ["elements"]),
               curried.map(lambda d: {
                   "section": get_in(["name"], d),
                   "type": get_in(["elements", "type"], d),
                   "module": get_in(["elements", "name"], d),
               }),
               list,
)

questions = pipe(data["records"],
                 lambda i: unwind(i, ["elements"]),
                 lambda i: unwind(i, ["elements", "elements"]),
                 curried.map(lambda d: {
                     "module": get_in(["elements", "name"], d),
                     "type": get_in(["elements", "elements", "type"], d),
                     "question": get_in(["elements", "elements", "name"], d),
                     "title": get_in(["elements", "elements", "title"], d),
                     "readOnly": get_in(["elements", "elements", "readOnly"], d),
                     "description": get_in(["elements", "elements", "description"], d),
                     "isRequired": get_in(["elements", "elements", "isRequired"], d),
                     "colCount": get_in(["elements", "elements", "colCount"], d),
                 }),
                 list,
)

choices = pipe(data["records"],
               lambda i: unwind(i, ["elements"]),
               lambda i: unwind(i, ["elements", "elements"]),
               lambda i: unwind(i, ["elements", "elements", "choices"]),
               curried.filter(lambda d: get_in(["elements", "elements", "choices"], d) is not None),
               curried.map(lambda d: {
                   "module": get_in(["elements", "name"], d),
                   "type": get_in(["elements", "elements", "type"], d),
                   "question": get_in(["elements", "elements", "name"], d),
                   "value": get_in(["elements", "elements", "choices", "value"], d),
                   "text": get_in(["elements", "elements", "choices", "text"], d),
               }),
               list,
)
```

Now you can create the dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_sections = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sections)
df_modules = pd.DataFrame.from_records(modules)
df_questions = pd.DataFrame.from_records(questions)
df_choices = pd.DataFrame.from_records(choices)
```

Comment: Thank you for help.Very well explained and presented.